# How to validate servlet request/response before writing to it?

Tags: java, validation, servlets

I have this problem of chrome submitting my request twice randomly for some reason unknown to me as I explain here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444861/servlet-called-twice-when-loading-small-pdf-files-on-chrome, I would very much like a solution to avoid double submitting but for now a patch will have to do.

In my servlet I read and write the PDF with the next lines of code:

```
        FileInputStream archivo = new FileInputStream(nFile);
        int longitud = archivo.available();
        byte[] datos = new byte[longitud];
        archivo.read(datos);
        archivo.close();

        OutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        ouputStream.write(datos);
        ouputStream.flush();
        ouputStream.close();
```

So, whenever chrome double submits I get the broken pipe exception at the line:

```
ouputStream.write(datos);
```

The second time I try to write to it.

How can I validate that "ouputStream" is valid before trying to write it so exception isn't thrown?

Or better yet, can I validate it at the filter?

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {

    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

How could I validate that I can write to response at this line of code?

```
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Also, it needs to be a servlet 2.3 solution.

Comment: What is the problem with just getting the exception? Does it break anything for you?

Comment: As matter of fact, it doesn't break anything for me, but why shouldn't it be avoided if you can avoid it? It is good to catch and handle exceptions properly, but I believe is better to avoid them.

Comment: This is a perfect use-case for an exception: An exceptional error situation. And in this case, there is not much you can do about it, except to log the error (which the default exception handler will do anyway). As for "avoiding", that can only meaningfully be done on the client side (but you are already working on that).

Comment: the problem is why your struts action is invoked twice for the same response object.

Comment: @bayou.io I know it is invoked twice for the same response object, but this can't be helped, this isn't done by the code, there's nothing in the code to make this happen, it is chrome that is doing it.

Comment: @Thilo I guess so, but I'm wondering if there's something that can be done. I only have a few months developing in Java, maybe somebody with more experience knows a work around.  I have read java docs and there's not much I could get to validate it. I guess exception handling will be, but I still hope someone has a fix/patch for this.

Comment: it can't be the browser; some bug on the server side.

Comment: Well, it doesn't happen on firefox, if you want to help, you can find a more detailed post of the real problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444861/servlet-called-twice-when-loading-small-pdf-files-on-chrome)